# How to make an animation of Nodes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a Node animation like this for SwiftUI --> https://oguzhaneroglu.com/projects/nodes.js/

That link has the source code (which is literally a small file) which I am converting.

The part I am confused on is, what is the equivalent in SwiftUI for this function?

```
 window[window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener': 'attachEvent']
    (window.addEventListener ? 'load': 'onload', function () {
```

I assume the contents in that function causes the animation to loop.
Can anyone give me any advice on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The part I am confused on is, what is the equivalent in SwiftUI for
> this function?
>
> ```
> window[window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener': 'attachEvent']
>     (window.addEventListener ? 'load': 'onload', function () {
> ```

Actually this is equivalent of `.onAppear` modifier on root view, so if original JS code activates animation in `function()`, then in SwiftUI we would do it as for example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
       VStack {            // << any view or container
          // ... other subviews
       }
       .onAppear(perform: function)
    }

    func function() {
        // ... any needed manipulations
    }
}
```

Comment: ..I know the original question was about the event listener function... but when I added the bounty for this question I wanted a little more help in creating this... For instance, I do not know how to make it continuous loop.. I gave a +1 for help.. but your help is very much needed :(

Comment: You need animation with `.repeatForever(...)` modifier. Without your code it is hard to say anything specific but next topics contain good examples where/how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64956536/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64566746/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61778318/12299030. And you can find more by `swiftui+repeatForever` keywords.

Comment: The code is me basically converting [this](https://github.com/rohanrhu/nodes.js/blob/master/js/nodes.js) to swift.  Its only a few lines of code because i don't need the mouse function starting on line 71.  
I will look at the examples you posted, and then check back here in the morning.

Comment: After looking at it closely, I don't think it can be done in SwiftUI. It Probably can be done with UIkit. Or if it can be done, It is not something I can do for my level. I will award you the points once stack overflow allows me to do so. thanks again.

Comment: @Asperi That was it. I was thinking in the wrong direction!

Comment: @swiftnub I posted an answer for you if it works.

Answer (score -1):

For my question, this HAD to be done in Swift. If this is not a strict requirement for you, then here is what you can do.

1. Put this inside a `node.html` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="nodes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nodesjs = new NodesJs({
            id: 'nodes',
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            particleSize: 4,
            lineSize: 2,
            particleColor: [85, 85, 121],
            lineColor: [255, 255, 255],
            backgroundDuration: 4000,
            number: window.hasOwnProperty('orientation') ? 30: 100,
            speed: 15
        });
    </script>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <canvas id="nodes"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Put this inside a `node.js` file

```js
var NodesJs = (function (parameters) {
    t_NodesJs = this;
    t_NodesJs.id = parameters.id;
    t_NodesJs.width = parameters.width;
    t_NodesJs.height = parameters.height;
    t_NodesJs.particleSize = parameters.particleSize ? parameters.particleSize: 2;
    t_NodesJs.lineSize = parameters.lineSize ? parameters.lineSize: 1;
    t_NodesJs.particleColor = parameters.particleColor ? 'rgba('+parameters.particleColor.join(',')+')': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)';
    t_NodesJs.lineColor = parameters.lineColor ? parameters.lineColor: '255,255,255';
    t_NodesJs.number = parameters.number ? parameters.number: 100;
    t_NodesJs.speed = parameters.speed ? parameters.speed: 20;

    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var cw;
    var ch;

    var t0 = Date.now();
    var dt = 0;

    t_NodesJs.nodes = [];

    t_NodesJs.setWidth = function (width) {
        canvas.width = width;
        cw = width;
    };

    t_NodesJs.setHeight = function (height) {
        canvas.height = height;
        ch = height;
    };

    t_NodesJs.placeNodes = function (number) {
        t_NodesJs.nodes = [];

        for (var i=0; i < number; i++) {
            t_NodesJs.nodes.push([
                Math.floor(Math.random() * (cw - 0 + 1)) + 0,
                Math.floor(Math.random() * (ch - 0 + 1)) + 0,
                Math.random() * (Math.PI * 2 - 0 + 1) + 0,
                []
            ]);
        }
    };

    var isPositive = function (num) {
        return num >= 0;
    };

    var isNetagive = function (num) {
        return num <= -1;
    };

    window[window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener': 'attachEvent']
    (window.addEventListener ? 'load': 'onload', function () {
        canvas = document.getElementById(t_NodesJs.id);
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = t_NodesJs.width;
        canvas.height = t_NodesJs.height;

        cw = canvas.width;
        ch = canvas.height;

        t_NodesJs.placeNodes(t_NodesJs.number);

        var step = function () {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
            
            // Fill the background
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb('+0+', '+0+', '+46+')';
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
            ctx.fill();
            
            t_NodesJs.nodes.forEach(function (_node, _node_i) {
                _node[0] += Math.cos(_node[2]) * t_NodesJs.speed * (dt/1000.0);
                _node[1] += Math.sin(_node[2]) * t_NodesJs.speed * (dt/1000.0);

                if (_node[0] < 0) {
                    _node[0] = cw + (_node[0] % cw);
                }

                if (_node[0] > cw) {
                    _node[0] = _node[0] % cw;
                }

                if (_node[1] < 0) {
                    _node[1] = ch + (_node[1] % ch);
                }

                if (_node[1] > ch) {
                    _node[1] = _node[1] % ch;
                }

                ctx.fillStyle = t_NodesJs.particleColor;

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(
                    _node[0],
                    _node[1],
                    t_NodesJs.particleSize,
                    0,
                    Math.PI * 2,
                    true
                );
                ctx.fill();

                _node[3] = [];

                t_NodesJs.nodes.forEach(function (_node2, _node2_i) {
                    if (_node_i == _node2_i) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (_node[3].indexOf(_node2_i) > -1) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    var dx = Math.abs(_node[0] - _node2[0]);
                    var dy = Math.abs(_node[1] - _node2[1]);
                    var d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));

                    var alpha = 0;

                    if (d <= 300) {
                        alpha = 0.3 - ((0.3 * d) / 200);
                    }

                    if (alpha == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    _node2[3].push(_node_i);

                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba('+t_NodesJs.lineColor+','+alpha+')';
                    ctx.lineWidth = t_NodesJs.lineSize;

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(_node[0], _node[1]);
                    ctx.lineTo(_node2[0], _node2[1]);
                    ctx.stroke();
                });
            });

            dt = Date.now() - t0;
            t0 = Date.now();
        };

        step();
    });
});
```

3. Add those 2 files to your project, then create a 3rd file called `WebView.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "node", withExtension: "html")!
        uiView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
}
```

Finally, add that `WebView` to what ever view you need on your iOS app. You now have the ability to do fancy animations of any html animations out there without knowing a lick of javascript.

Let me know if this works for you.