# Blinking symbol with didSet in SwiftUI

Tags: class, struct, swiftui, didset

This is synthesized from a much larger app. I'm trying to blink an SF symbol in SwiftUI by activating a timer in a property's didSet. A print statement inside timer prints the expected value but the view doesn't update.

I'm using structs throughout my model data and am guessing this will have something to do with value vs. reference types. I'm trying to avoid converting from structs to classes.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

@main
struct TestBlinkApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items: [Item] = []
  
  static var loadData: Model {
    let model = Model()
    model.items = [Item("Item1"), Item("Item2"), Item("Item3"), Item("Item4")]
    
    return model
  }
}

struct Item {
  static let ledBlinkTimer: TimeInterval = 0.5
  
  private let ledTimer = Timer.publish(every: ledBlinkTimer, tolerance: ledBlinkTimer * 0.1, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect()
  
  private var timerSubscription: AnyCancellable? = nil
  
  var name: String
  
  var isLEDon = false
  
  var isLedBlinking = false {
    didSet {
      var result = self
      print("in didSet: isLedBlinking: \(result.isLedBlinking) isLEDon: \(result.isLEDon)")
      guard result.isLedBlinking else {
        result.isLEDon = true
        result.ledTimer.upstream.connect().cancel()
        print("Cancelling timer.")
        return
      }
      result.timerSubscription = result.ledTimer
        .sink {  _ in
          result.isLEDon.toggle()
          print("\(result.name) in ledTimer isLEDon: \(result.isLEDon)")
        }
    }
  }
  
  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}


struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var model = Model.loadData
  
  let color = Color(UIColor.label)
  
  public var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(model.items[0].name)
      Image(systemName: model.items[0].isLEDon ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
        .foregroundColor(model.items[0].isLEDon ? .green : color)
      Button("Toggle") {
        model.items[0].isLedBlinking.toggle()
      }
    }
    .foregroundColor(color)
  }
}
```

Touching the "Toggle" button starts the timer that's suppose to blink the circle. The print statement shows the value changing but the view doesn't update. Why??

Comment: You can use a forever repeating animation instead of a timer.

Comment: OK. Pardon my ignorance but some code would be really useful to get me going ...

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61778318/12299030?

Comment: I don't see how. The view blinks forever. I need to control the blinking programmatically.

Comment: @Phantom59: sorry; I have provided an answer with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animation to make it blink, instead of a timer.

The model of `Item` gets simplified, you just need a boolean variable, like this:

```
struct Item {
    
    var name: String
    
    // Just a toggle: blink/ no blink
    var isLedBlinking = false

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

The "hard work" is done by the view: changing the variable triggers or stops the blinking. The animation does the magic:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model.loadData
    
    let color = Color(UIColor.label)
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.items[0].name)
                .padding()
            
            // Change based on isLedBlinking
            Image(systemName: model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? .green : color)
            
                // Animates the view based on isLedBlinking: when is blinking, blinks forever, otherwise does nothing
                .animation(model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? .easeInOut.repeatForever() : .default, value: model.items[0].isLedBlinking)
                .padding()
            
            Button("Toggle: \(model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? "Blinking" : "Still")") {
                model.items[0].isLedBlinking.toggle()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a slight glitch that I've tried unsuccessfully to eliminate. The blinking occurs between solid green and solid black. Why? The intent was for the blinking to occur between circle.fill (solid green) and circle empty (black outline). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Phantom59: I didn't realise the glitch, but if you find it, the solution is: have 2 separate views, one for the empty black and one for the solid green circles, and show them using `if model.items[0].isLedBlinking { emptyBlackCircle } else { solidGreenCircle }`. Then, instead of using the `.animation()` modifier, wrap the action inside the button with `withAnimation(!model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? .easeInOut.repeatForever() : .default) { ...toggle command here... }`. The exclamation mark in `!model` is because `isLedBlinking` starts with a `false` value.

Comment: If I followed you correctly, this is what I'm using:  Button("Toggle: \(model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? "Blinking" : "Still")") {  withAnimation(!model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? .easeInOut.repeatForever() : .default) {  model.items[0].isLedBlinking.toggle() } }

Blinking looks nice but this causes the button to blink.

Comment: @Phantom59: that’s because the text depends on the status of “isLedBlinking”. Either you go back to a static text, like the one you have in your original code, or you use another variable only for the text that does not animate.

Comment: Yes, I know that. It was just a comment. Thanks, again, for the answer and intro to animations (modifiers and otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

A different approach with a timer:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var model = Model.loadData
  
  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.25, tolerance: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
  
  let color = Color(UIColor.label)
  
  public var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(model.items[0].name)
      
      if model.items[0].isLedBlinking {
        Image(systemName: model.items[0].isLEDon ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
          .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            model.items[0].isLEDon.toggle()
          }
          .foregroundColor(model.items[0].isLEDon ? .green : color)
      } else {
        Image(systemName: model.items[0].isLEDon ? "circle.fill" : "circle")
          .foregroundColor(model.items[0].isLEDon ? .green : color)
      }
      
      Button("Toggle: \(model.items[0].isLedBlinking ? "Blinking" : "Still")") {
        model.items[0].isLedBlinking.toggle()
      }
    }
    .foregroundColor(color)
  }
}
```