# SwiftUI Confetti Animation

Tags: animation, swiftui, swiftui-animation

Note: I solved the issue. If you are interested in the animation, I created a package with SPM and is available on https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI

So I am trying to create a confetti animation in SwiftUI. This is what I have so far:

[image]

This works all as expected and is done with the following code:

```swift
struct Movement{
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    var z: CGFloat
    var opacity: Double
}

struct FancyButtonViewModel: View {
    @State var animate = [false]
    @State var finishedAnimationCouter = 0
    @State var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                ForEach(finishedAnimationCouter...counter, id:\.self){ i in
                    ConfettiContainer(animate:$animate[i], finishedAnimationCouter:$finishedAnimationCouter, num:1)
                }
            }
            
            Button("Confetti"){
                animate[counter].toggle()
                animate.append(false)
                counter+=1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ConfettiContainer: View {
    @Binding var animate:Bool
    @Binding var finishedAnimationCouter:Int

    var num:Int
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            ForEach(0...num-1, id:\.self){ _ in
                Confetti(animate: $animate, finishedAnimationCouter:$finishedAnimationCouter)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: animate){_ in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.5) {
                finishedAnimationCouter+=1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Confetti: View{
    @Binding var animate:Bool
    @Binding var finishedAnimationCouter:Int
    @State var movement = Movement(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, opacity: 0)
    

    var body: some View{
        Text("❤️")
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .offset(x: movement.x, y: movement.y)
            .scaleEffect(movement.z)
            .opacity(movement.opacity)
            .onChange(of: animate) { _ in
                withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.4)) {
                    movement.opacity = 1
                    movement.x = CGFloat.random(in: -150...150)
                    movement.y = -300 * CGFloat.random(in: 0.7...1)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 3)) {
                        movement.y = 200
                        movement.opacity = 0.0
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to replace the Heart Emoji with an animated confetti view. Thus, I created the following view:

```swift
struct ConfettiView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    @State var xSpeed = Double.random(in: 0.7...2)
    @State var zSpeed = Double.random(in: 1...2)
    @State var anchor = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1).rounded()
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
            .onAppear(perform: { animate = true })
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 360:0), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: xSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 360:0), axis: (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1), anchor: UnitPoint(x: anchor, y: anchor))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: zSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
    }
}
```

[image]

This works as expected as well. However, if I replace the `Text("❤️")` with. `ConfettiView()` I get some unexpected animation as shown below. (I reduced the number of confettis to 1 so the animation can be observed better). What does the animation break?

[image]

Comment: good news, you are going about this completely wrong!

Amazingly, iOS has a particle animation system completely built-in.  full tutorial:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43075797/294884

Comment: Good to know thank you but this a experiment that should only use pure SwiftUI

Comment: for sure!  I would really encourage you to do it, perhaps as a test, in SwiftUI, with a particle system.  u'll be amazed at the performance and flexibility. Good luck !!!  looking good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animations overlaps, to solve you need to join inner one with state value.

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct ConfettiView: View {
    @State var animate = false
    @State var xSpeed = Double.random(in: 0.7...2)
    @State var zSpeed = Double.random(in: 1...2)
    @State var anchor = CGFloat.random(in: 0...1).rounded()
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
            .onAppear(perform: { animate = true })
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 360:0), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: xSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animate)
            .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 360:0), axis: (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1), anchor: UnitPoint(x: anchor, y: anchor))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: zSpeed).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps also know why the animation breaks for some of the confettis if I replace `Rectangle()` with `shapes.randomElement()` where shapes is defined as `let shapes:[AnyView] = [AnyView(Rectangle()), AnyView(Circle())]`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the code above, very useful for my project.

However, instead of clicking, I have embedded the animation generation within a timer:

```
func startConfettiTimer()  {
    confettiTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true, block: { _ in
        confettiAnimate[confettiCounter].toggle()
        confettiAnimate.append(false)
        confettiCounter+=1
    })
    _ = confettiTimer
}

func stopConfettiTimer() {
    confettiTimer?.invalidate()
}
```

Full code here:
[Github](https://github.com/naydon/confettiForSwiftUI/blob/main/README.md)